# how to custom connect the database from yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Im trying to connect the db in yii connection how can i do that ?

In below screen shot there is an cron.php i have trying to connect the database from root folder how to d that ?

**Cron.php**

```
require('framework/db/CDbConnection.php');    

$connection=new CDbConnection($dsn,'root','');
$connection->active=true;
```

I need to use Yii connection instead of mysql

```
 $mysql_con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
 mysql_select_db('som',$mysql_con); //local DB
```

[image: Cron]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `cron` for some tasks, consider creating [yii console application](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console) commands. Configure it to use your db settings and call tasks that you need like that `yiic <command-name> <action-name>`

Comment: cant able to connect the db from external ?

Comment: you can, but if you want/need to use Yii connection, i think its more reliable and convenient way to do this. you just need to create command and action, configure console app to use db settings and you are ready to go. also you get all benefits of framework

Comment: without that ? i cant able to connect the db ?

Comment: The point here is that when you do it in console app, yii will autoload classes that you need. If you want just `CDbConnection` class you need to require all its dependencies manually, or configure autoloading by yourself, which is more work for you